# MongoDB query works partially

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

The below query works fine but not the date part, it takes the date out the mentioned window, please can you provide inputs

```
db.getCollection('RS').find(
  {"tradeKeys.bod" : {$in : ["25498","132387","26213","79054","25631"]}},
  {"Id" : 1, "tradeKeys.pId" : 1, "tradeKeys.tId" : 1, "tradeKeys.bod" : 1,"tradeKeys.pat" : 1, "currentFrom" : 1, "UIDs" : 1},
  {"tradeKeys.tId" : "000000289"},
  {"tradeKeys.pat" : {$in : ["ABCD", "EFGH"]}},
  {"currentFrom" : { $gte: ISODate("2021-04-29T00:00:00.000Z"), $lt:  ISODate("2021-05-02T00:00:00.000Z")}}
)
```

Comment: [db.collection.find()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#mongodb-method-db.collection.find) only takes 2 arguments, it looks like you have 3 there

Comment: Also, see the usage of [$and](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) query operator.

Comment: you might need to aggregate your query

Answer (score 0):

The `find` method only [takes two arguments](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find--), where the first one is the query, and the second one the projection.

So you will need to merge the last three objects into the first one.

```
db.getCollection('RS').find(
  {
    "tradeKeys.bod" : {$in : ["25498","132387","26213","79054","25631"]},
    "tradeKeys.tId" : "000000289",
    "tradeKeys.pat" : {$in : ["ABCD", "EFGH"]},
    "currentFrom" : {
       $gte: ISODate("2021-04-29T00:00:00.000Z"),
       $lt:  ISODate("2021-05-02T00:00:00.000Z")
    }
  },
  {
    "Id" : 1,
    "tradeKeys.pId" : 1,
    "tradeKeys.tId" : 1,
    "tradeKeys.bod" : 1,
    "tradeKeys.pat" : 1,
    "currentFrom" : 1,
    "UIDs" : 1
  }
)
```